# help for a java assignment

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I want to write a messenger application with java. I want to send smily pictures. I have written this code but it doesn’t work.

```
public class MyClient extends JFrame implements IClient {
```

…

```
JEditorPane editorPane=new JEditorPane();
final String SMILE = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("images/1.gif").toString();
```

…

```
public void chat(String message) {
        try {
            StringBuffer  bfr= new StringBuffer(message);

            while(message.indexOf(":)") != -1) {
                int index = message.indexOf(":)");
                bfr.replace(index,index+2,"<IMG SRC=\""+SMILE +"\">");
                message= bfr.toString();

            }

try{
            editorPane.getEditorKit().read(new java.io.StringReader(message+"\n"),
                    editorPane.getDocument(), editorPane.getDocument().getLength());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    editorPane.setCaretPosition(editorPane.getDocument().getLength());
    }
```

…
But it desnt show the smily in the editorpane, the output is : 

It is the address with which the smily has been saved.
I cast the code like this:

```
(HTMLEditorKit)editorPane.getEditorKit().read(new java.io.StringReader(message+"\n"),
                    editorPane.getDocument(), editorPane.getDocument().getLength());
```

but it causes exception as this cast isn’t correct. So what I can I do?
thank

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possibilities:

1. you define a control string (like in msn) where :) becomes the smiley gif (for this one the receiver must have the gif too - so I'd go for an image folder that contains all gifs)
2. you have to read the gif-file and transfer the content of the file to the receiver who then can display it (that's the more difficult solution)

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found the answer. i just assigned the HTMLEditorKit as my the editorkit of my JEditorPane